# removing row from database through delete button in a php table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a little control panel so I can add and delete rows in a database.
I've already made the adding part work but I'm having some trouble with the deleting.

The page shows every row in a table and I've added a delete button behind it.

This are the codes I have

This is the code that makes the table:

```
<table class='col-sm-6 fixed_headers'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style='height:250px; overflow:auto;'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 "<tr class=". $row['ID'] . ">";
 echo "<td>" . $row['uname'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['pass'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td><input type='submit' class='button' id=".$row['ID'] . " value='del'></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</tbody>
 </table>";
?>
```

Here is the ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    var btnID = $(this).id;


  jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/delete.php",
        data:  {id :btnID}
    }).done(function(result){
    if(result== "succes"){
        $('#error').remove();
        $('#succes').html("Het account is verwijderd. ");

    }else {
        $('#error').empty();
        $('#error').html("Er is een fout opgetreden.<br/> Probeer opnieuw! ");
    }
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

and here is the delete.php:

```
$id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$delete = "DELETE FROM `xxx`.`xxx` WHERE `xxx`.`ID` = '$id'"; 
$del = mysql_query($delete);

if ($del)
{
    echo "succes";

}
else
{
    echo "error";
    // close connection 
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

when I press the delete button, I do get the succes message but the row hasn't been deleted of my database.

I have been trying to fix this, but I can't seem to make it work

(left out my db connect code)

Comment: what is `xxx`.`xxx` is it a table or a column xxx in a table xxx ?

Comment: it's the name of the table

Answer (score 2):

My Advice to you, is to NEVER delete from your database.

Instead, add a boolean variable to your table, which is by default set to '1' and whenever you want to "delete" a row, Set your bool to '0'.

When you query your table to show on your page, query WHERE boolVariable = '1'.

For security reasons, this is the best approach, and make sure to remove the "delete" priviledge from the Db user you're using to connect to your database

---

One more thing, stop using mysql_query, and use mysqli_query as mysql_ is deprecated

source: [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Comment: thx for the advice! Do you also know what is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Did you forget to add ';' at the end of your sql query ? 
$delete = "DELETE FROM `xxx`.`xxx` WHERE `xxx`.`ID` = '$id';";

Comment: @RalphMelhem : you can do that `$id';`, but is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Changing $(this).id to $(this).attr('id') fixed it